# Why does ls show different size for some directories (not 4k)?

Tags: command-line, directory, ls

While `ls` shows most directories having a size of `4.0K`, some directories have different sizes, as shown in the output below:

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Aug 13  2022 room
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  138 Jan 11  2021 room_old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Aug 12  2022 room_new
```

Why does `ls` show different size for some directories (not 4k)?

Comment: Is `room_old` a mountpoint for some other filesystem?

Comment: they are on the same disk, does it copy from other fielsystem can keep old file meta info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really the size of the contents of the directory, but it's rather how much space on disk is used to store the meta data(*e.g. about it and it's **immediate** contents inode numbers and names/paths*) of that directory.

To simplify it, think of a directory similar to a [Telephone directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_directory) ... i.e. the more names, numbers and addresses it contains, the larger in size it becomes and vice versa.

Please see the demonstration below:

```bash
# Block size
$ stat -fc %s .
4096
# Create empty directories
$ mkdir 1 2 3
$ ls -lh
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar  8 11:43 1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar  8 11:43 2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar  8 11:43 3
# Create multiple empty 0 size files
$ touch 1/file{1..1000}
$ touch 2/file{1..100000}
# Create a 1G size file
$ fallocate -l 1G 3/file1
$ ls -lh
total 2.7M
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  28K Mar  8 11:44 1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 2.6M Mar  8 11:44 2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar  8 11:44 3
$ du -sh *
28K     1
2.6M    2
1.1G    3
# Copy a more populated directory with larger meta-info size under another less populated directory
$ cp -r 2/ 3/
$ ls -lh
total 2.7M
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  28K Mar  8 11:44 1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 2.6M Mar  8 11:44 2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar  8 11:44 3
$ ls -lh 3/
total 1.1G
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 2.6M Mar  8 11:44 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1.0G Mar  8 11:44 file1
```

**Notice** that the minimum allocatable size for directory metadata/information depends on the file system ... e.g. on Ubuntu **EXT4**, it defaults to the block size(*find it with e.g. `stat -fc %s .`*) ... Other filesystems, however, might utilize less/more than that ... e.g. on **NTFS**:

```bash
# Block size
$ stat -fc %s .
4096
# Create an empty directory
$ mkdir dir_on_ntfs
$ ls -lh
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_ntfs
# Populate the directory with multiple empty 0 size files
$ touch  dir_on_ntfs/file{1..10000}
$ ls -lh
total 2.0M
drwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2.0M Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_ntfs
```

And on **XFS**:

```bash
# Block size
$ stat -fc %s .
4096
# Create an empty directory
$ mkdir dir_on_xfs
$ ls -lh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 6 Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_xfs
# Populate the directory with multiple empty 0 size files
$ touch dir_on_xfs/file{1..10000}
$ ls -lh
total 376K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 240K Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_xfs
```

While on **VFAT**:

```bash
# Block size
$ stat -fc %s .
32768
# Create an empty directory
$ mkdir dir_on_vfat
$ ls -lh
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 32K Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_vfat
# Populate the directory with multiple empty 0 size files
$ touch  dir_on_vfat/file{1..10000}
$ ls -lh
total 640K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 640K Mar  8 13:32 dir_on_vfat
```

Comment: does it mean directory size always big than 4k?  why a 138 byte size shows ?

Comment: randall That could be the reason why @muru asked in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458323/why-ls-show-diffrent-size-for-directoriesnot-4k#comment2551038_1458323) i.e. that different directory could be a mountpoint of or mounted from another FS ... I also updated the answer for that.

Comment: I checked the format , it 's xfs, and they are on the same disk, wired

Comment: they are on the same disk, does it copy from other fielsystem can keep old file meta info?

Comment: I run the command stat below, it shows:    File: ‘room_old’
  Size: 138         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory

Comment: @randall "*does it copy from other fielsystem can keep old file meta info?*" ... No, copying should result in the directory recreation in the destination FS following its rules.

Comment: @randall They could be on the same disk but different partitions/filesystems ... A directory can also be a mount point for another filesystem ... You can check if the case is the latter one with e.g. `mount | grep -i "room_old"` ... I can't do your homework :-)

Comment: thanks a lot , i found a similar question here https://superuser.com/questions/585844/why-directories-size-are-different-in-ls-l-output-on-xfs-file-system