# After replacing the charging port on a pavilion laptop I'm getting system freezes and orphaned inodes showing up during reboot

Tags: freeze, inode

The time to failure is highly variable with the longest operating run being ~13 hours fsck never reports any problems and shutting down before a freeze happens produces a clean restart with no orphaned inodes in the startup sequence. one recovery check of the file system (esc f2 during boot) showed 1 damaged file but I can't get that to replicate. smartctl output to follow:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-75-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     WD Blue / Red / Green SSDs
Device Model:     WDC  WDS500G2B0A-00SM50
Serial Number:    213212806522
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 8bc61fb2d
Firmware Version: 415020WD
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jun 29 10:35:01 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       11839
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       214
165 Block_Erase_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       382465936243
166 Minimum_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
167 Max_Bad_Blocks_per_Die  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       64
168 Maximum_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       18
169 Total_Bad_Blocks        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       268
170 Grown_Bad_Blocks        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Average_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       9
174 Unexpected_Power_Loss   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       47
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   076   040   ---    Old_age   Always       -       24 (Min/Max 11/40)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   005   005   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0x0556005a0556
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
233 NAND_GB_Written_TLC     0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4897
234 NAND_GB_Written_SLC     0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       21766
241 Host_Writes_GiB         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       16387
242 Host_Reads_GiB          0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       5417
244 Temp_Throttle_Status    0x0032   000   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     11838         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: so what is the actual problem? Your system crashes sometimes now? Because you say everything is fine when you shut down normally, does that mean sometimes it shuts down abnormally? Sounds like a hardware issue then, if you recently replaced hardware.

Comment: It is normal for filesystem errors to occur when a system crashes, the solution to this is *not to let your system crash*. What you need to fix is not the filesystem, but rather the system crashes.

Comment: Related: [WARNING: Filesystem system has error. couldn't fIx parent of node 47322B43 Couldn't find parent directory entry](https://askubuntu.com/q/1466977)

Comment: As @Esther noted, you better fix what cases dirty shutdowns first, because not all filesystem errors can be easily fixed by disk checking utilities ... You are lucky so far so don't wait until the inevitable happens.

Comment: Right I'm asking to find the cause of this error. There is no indication of anything wrong until the system freezes at which point its too late. The only symptom is some orphaned inodes and none of the logging or monitoring I've looked at claims there are any problems. The only change is the hardware that the charger plugs into and I can't find a software check for that. Are there suggestions for ways to learn about the the system crashes in ways that would allow them to be fixed?