# Error on Ubuntu boot up - it stays in recovering journal. How can I solve this?

Tags: boot, nvidia, recovery-mode

I have a problem when starting my Ubuntu machine. The problem appeared right after doing:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* libnvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

After the machine came back to life, I got the message `/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, n/n files, n/n blocks` instead of actually initializing Ubuntu (the desktop).

[image]

I have tried several things, this solution among them [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal) but it didn't work; I got an error when doing fsck -f / since there is something mounted there.

I have also tried removing all the Nvidia drivers installed and using purge and auto remove for that. I have come back to the nouveau driver, and rebooted, but nothing works.

Please be detailed in your answers if you can.

Comment: Do the `clearing orphaned inode`  lines appear on every boot? or only once?

Comment: They appeared only one time. In the reboots after that, only the last line showed upp. I found a solution for this, which I will post in a moment.

Comment: That should be normal and no need to do anything ... [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1467086) might have some useful information on how a filesystem works ... The message is printed most of the time but covered with the splash screen or appears very briefly ... It goes to boot logs ... It's just that you haven't noticed it before.

Comment: The problem was that the machine didn't enter the desktop. It was frozen there.

Comment: That is irrelevant to the error and is probably caused by the graphics drivers you changed ... So, focus on that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem doing the following:

- boot to the GRUB menu (pressed the shift key many times once the DELL icon showed up on my screen).
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- remove any nvidia-related thing with `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
- `sudo apt purge *535*` (I had installed the 535 driver before the problem)
- `sudo apt autoremove`
- `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
- `sudo reboot`

I still got the recovering journal after this reboot, so I went back to the Recovery Mode and did:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`

This prompt a secure boot set up, I fixed that and then boot successfully.

Note: install the driver that is adequate to your machine. It may not be the 535.