# at boot time - recovering journal

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery

I have dual boot - Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I know for sure that last time Ubuntu was shutdown gracefully.
But today when i opted Ubuntu Linux from grub menu then I am getting this message:
recovering journal

and it stays for quite some time...
[image]

Anybody faced this kind of issue.

After trying this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal)
I am getting this
[image]

In fact Windows also facing some issue. Seems to be the case that some disk drive has got some issue.

**Finally the only thing that worked was fresh install of Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS**

Answer (score 1):

If it's that one time or even several times over a long period of time, then it's normal and there is nothing you need to do or worry about as your system is reported `clean`(*no filesystem errors detected*) ... Sometimes errors would be found and automatically fixed and that would also be normal and nothing needed to be done from your side.

This is probably the first time you notice it, but it most likely has happened before and might(*"will happen"*) happen later ... You might find some already had happened if you look into the logs with like for example:

```
sudo grep -2 'recovering journal' /var/log/boot*
```

Shutting down Ubuntu gracefully does not guarantee a clean filesystem as other things could happen ... Also a filesystem check triggered at boot doesn't necessarily mean a big catastrophe has happened ... In fact most of the time, the filesystem will report as `clean` like in your case and other times the problem is minor and limited to a single or few inodes like for example a deleted file/directory that its inode was not properly freed due to it was being held open by a process when it was deleted.

Please, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1467086) which might shed some light on what might trigger a filesystem check as well as what might need user intervention regarding that.

Comment: Finally the only thing that worked was fresh install of Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS