# Not able to delete a file even if using sudo command on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, sudo, files, filesystem, delete

[image: This is the ls -l result]

I have a text file `Summary_DataTypes.txt` which was created by me earlier. It appears in `ls`and vs code. But does not show in the folder even if I do show hidden folder.
I want to delete this file but `sudo rm -f` also not able to delete it.
I also tried deleting it with `sudo -s` but it did not get delete.

I am getting

`Error when getting information for file "fileName" : Input/Outout error.`

Comment: You'll have to give specifics, including the name of this file and its permissions.  It is possible that the file you are trying to delete is being created by a program that is running.  Of course there are other reasons as well.

Comment: @Ray Linux allows holding open descriptors to files without any hard links (i.e. deleted), so "being created" feels unlikely.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus service running on your system? that can prevent any type of access to a certain file ... Also filesystem-level encryption can do that as well.

Comment: @ Ray I have mentioned the file name and attached a Screen Shot as well.

@ Raffa - No anti-virus service running on my system

Comment: Oh, that looks like a filesystem corruption ... Short answer run a filesystem check and let it fix errors ... Long answer see https://askubuntu.com/a/1467086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Linux man pages for `unlink(2)`, the system call behind `rm`:

> ### ERRORS
>
> EFAULT
>
> *pathname* points outside your accessible address space.
>
> EIO
>
> An I/O error occurred.
>
> ...
>
> ...

...and `EIO`'s error string is exactly "Input/output error."

So, I think I can assume that this is more likely a hardware or data corruption issue, instead of anything related to permissions etc.

###### P.S. (after edit)

I am confident that this is inode corruption now. Best course of action is to unmount the device (or reboot to a rescue drive if it is stored on root) and run fsck.

Comment: I agree with this ... Most likely filesystem corruption and less likely hardware/connection failure (bad /degraded blocks included) although possible ... Notice that "data corruption" in itself i.e. data contained in the file is not likely a problem here but rather data storage structure i.e. filesystem can do that.

Comment: ... Although judging by directory sizes of `0` in OP screenshot, the filesystem might be NTFS and in this case a filesystem check under Windows is advised.

Comment: @mcendu : I got this error msg at vs code also while opening this file. Got convinced that this is something data corruption error. As I am using aria2 for downloading torrents and there is a file .aria2 which tracks the state of the download today suddenly this file got deleted by its own and I ran my usual aria2 command to resume. Hence many folders were showing the same error. But It made me post here when I saw the same error with above mentioned file. As that file was not the part of aria2 downloads.

Comment: @Raffa : Thank you Sir, for this solution. It worked. I have a dual boot windows 11  + Ubuntu 22.04 and when I boot from w11 while booting Windows fixed it itself.